# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParamter type objects, not String objects

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Records ([Student ID], [First Name], [Last Name], " + 
                  "[Middle Initial], Gender, Address, Status, Year, Email, Course, " + 
                  "[Contact Number]) VALUES ( @Student ID,  @First Name, @Last Name, " + 
                  "@Middle Initial, @Gender, @Address, @Status, @Year, @Email, " + 
                  "@Course, @Contact Number)";

        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@[Student ID]", SqlDbType.Int);
        p1.Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("1");
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@First Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p2.Value = textBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p2");
        SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@Last Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        p3.Value = textBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p3");
        SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@Middle Initial", SqlDbType.NChar);
        p4.Value = comboBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p4");
        SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@Gender", SqlDbType.NChar);
        p5.Value = comboBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p5");
        SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p6.Value = textBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p6");
        SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.NChar);
        p7.Value = comboBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p7");
        SqlParameter p8 = new SqlParameter("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p8.Value = comboBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p8");
        SqlParameter p9 = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p9.Value = textBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("9");
        SqlParameter p10 = new SqlParameter("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p10.Value = comboBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p10");
        SqlParameter p11 = new SqlParameter("@Contact Number", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        p11.Value = textBox6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p11");

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: read title next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the instance of the parameter to the collection, not the string "p11"

```
    SqlParameter p11 = new SqlParameter("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    p11.Value = textBox6.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p11);
```

And you don't need to make your life difficult with spaces in parameter names.

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Records ([Student ID], [First Name], [Last Name], " + 
                  "[Middle Initial], Gender, Address, Status, Year, Email, Course, " + 
                  "[Contact Number]) VALUES ( @StudentID,  @FirstName, @LastName, " + 
                  "@MiddleInitial, @Gender, @Address, @Status, @Year, @Email, " + 
                  "@Course, @ContactNumber)";

.....

// Name your parameters without spaces
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@StudentID", SqlDbType.Int);
p1.Value = textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
.....
```

The parameters placeholders inside the command text will be replaced by the value of the parameter with the same name, no need to complicate things adding spaces inside the parameter placeholder.

Comment: I just did what you said but it has another error 
Incorrect syntax near 'int'.
Must declare the scalar variable "@Student".

Comment: Remove the spaces in the placeholders: `@Student ID` should be `@StudentID` (without spaces) and the parameter `p1` should have the same name of the placeholder `"@StudentID"`. Apply the same logic to all the other parameters

Comment: Thanks! it works for me im having a hard time with this parameter. again thx :)